# firebase onAuthStateChanged listener run instantly when user is logged in or not?

Tags: typescript, next.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

```
//initialize auth change listener
useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            router.replace('/')
        }
    })
    setInitializing(false)
}, [])

//*handled by login button
const login = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (!form.email || !form.password) {
        setError('Email Id and Password not found')
        return
    }
    try {
        await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, form.email, form.password)
        const idToken = await getIdToken()

        //if userId and password is wrong
        //return with an error
        if (!idToken) {
            setError('Invalid User')
            await signOut(auth)
            return
        }

        //retrieve user data from firestore
        const _getUser = await getUser(idToken!)

        //if no user found
        //return with an error
        if (_getUser.error) {
            alert(_getUser.error)
            setError(_getUser.error)
            await signOut(auth)
            return
        }

        //if user is found
        //store jwt token in cookie
        document.cookie = `{"jwt":${_getUser.jwt}}`
    } catch (e: any) {
        // console.log(e.message);
    }
}
```

*Explaination->*
`useEffect` initialized `onAuthStateChanged` listener and if user is found then  it should instantly redirect the user to **'/' route**

`login function` try to sign in using email id and password (using `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`)

After handling some time-consuming tasks using await, set `document.cookie = 'boo:foo'` (last line in try block)

*Question->*
onAuthStateChanged should redirect the user to **'/' route** instantly after `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` is resolved with a user but it wait until the `login function` is run completely or document.cookie is set. Why?

framework using  - NEXT JS

language - Typescript

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript (in this context) is inherently a single-threaded language, and it seems that it can't get to calling your `onAuthStateChanged` handler until after your `login` function is done with its synchronous work.

You *could* put the code you want to keep from blocking the handler in a block like this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  // code that runs later goes here
}, 0);
```

A construct like this ensure that the event loop has a change to execute other code, before running the code inside this block.